# Microsoft Bot - MemoryStorage - Error - Etag conflict

Tags: botframework

I am try to save data to the MemoryStorage in Microsoft Bot Frame Work (in .NET environment).

I am using this method for do it:

```
public static class StateManager
{
    private static MemoryStorage _myStorage;

    static StateManager()
    {
        _myStorage = new MemoryStorage();
    }

    public async static void Save(UserDetails userDetails)
    {

            var changes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            {
                changes.Add("ud", userDetails);
            }
            await _myStorage.WriteAsync(changes, new CancellationToken());

    }
}
```

until now it's always work fine. but suddenly i am getting this error:

> System.Exception: Etag conflict. Original: 4 Current: 5

any idea how to solve this error? thanks!

**edit - with solve**

I got that the problem was that i push data to the memory twice in a row (without get the data between the tow pushes). it's mean that after i push data one time, i have to get the data from the storage before i push the data again.

My question now it's why? i cannot save data twice without get the data between the tow pushes?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code, I wasn't able to replicate your issue. However, it sounds like you have a concurrency problem.

Your `Save()` method returns a `void`. You should instead use:

`public async static Task Save(UserDetails userDetails)`

Then, when saving, call with:

`await StateManager.Save(userDetails)`.

However, you can save yourself the trouble of these kinds of things and use BotBuilder's built-in state storage. References:

[Save User and Conversation Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

[Core Bot Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot) - This is an example of good user profile storage

Comment: Your Basic Bot Sample link is not working. Could you please send the updated link?

Comment: @RohanRao Done. We've since renamed it to Core Bot.